# I want to use a inputbox e.g. to choose G:F or K:K ...look at my code:

Tags: excel, vba

i want to pop up a inputbox when LR is coming..
Look in code:

`LR = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("G2:G" & LR).Select`

```
Sub FixIt()

Dim LR As Long
    LR = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("G2:G" & LR).Select

Selection.Replace What:=Chr(160), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False

Selection.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False

Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
Selection.Style = "Comma"

End Sub
```

Comment: So you want to replace the LR = ... part by a combobox value?

Comment: Stein, your code selects the last cell in column G, removes Chr(160) form its content, replaces commas with periods, sets the number format and the style - all for that one cell. I don't understand at which point in this action "LR is coming", nor what the input box might do when that event occurs.

Comment: Hey!
Ist not only for one cell, but for all cells below e.g G2.. column.
but i want to have an option to choose another columm .. e. g from J2 or K2.

Comment: Is it possible to replace
    `Dim LR As Long

    LR = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("G2:G" & LR).Select`

with an inpupbox who select same range or what u choose in that inputbox?

Comment: If the answer is satisfactory, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Application.InputBox` with `Type:=8` to specify an input box which will have as its return value a `Range` object.

Here is an example of using such an input box to get the *row* number of a selected cell.

```
Dim inRange as Range
Set inRange = Application.InputBox("Please select a cell...", Type:=8)
If Not inRange Is Nothing Then
    LR = inRange.Row
Else
    'Probably you want to Exit Sub here or do some error-handling
End If
```

Or, to use the same approach to get the entire range of selection:

```
Dim myRange as Range
Set myRange = Application.InputBox("Please select some range...", Type:=8)
If myRange Is Nothing Then
    'Probably you want to Exit Sub here or do some error-handling
End If
'proceed with the rest of your code...

With myRange
    .Replace What:=Chr(160), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    .Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    .NumberFormat = "0.00" Selection.Style = "Comma"
End With
```